# Why are this two empty arrays of arrays being filled differently?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this code. I even put console.logs to debug it. But I really don't understand why are they behaving in a different way. Why do the result1 array fill all the internal arrays with the last array values?

```js
var myMatrix = [
  [0, 1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6, 7],
  [8, 9, 10, 11],
  [12, 13, 14, 15]
];

function rotateMatrixClockwise(matrix) {
  var long = matrix.length;
  var result1 = new Array(long).fill([]);
  var result2 = [ [], [], [], [] ];
  console.log("Empty result1:");
  console.log(result1);
  console.log("Empty result2:");
  console.log(result2);
  for (var row = 0; row < long; row++) {
    for (var col = 0; col < long; col++) {
      result1[row][col] = matrix[long - col - 1][row];
      result2[row][col] = matrix[long - col - 1][row];
    }
  }
  console.log("Result1:");
  console.log(result1);
  console.log("Result2:");
  console.log(result2);
}

rotateMatrixClockwise(myMatrix);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are filling the array with the same object reference of the array in

```
var result1 = new Array(long).fill([]);
//                                 ^^ same array for all elements
```

Any assignment later takes place in the same array.

In the working version,

```
var result2 = [[], [], [], []];
//             ^^  ^^  ^^  ^^  four different arrays
```

you takes four different arrays, which have no reference to the same array.

The reference for [`Array.fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) states the static behavior, and while Javascript, objects are handed over by reference.

> The **`fill()`** method fills all the elements of an array from a start index to an end index with a static value.

```js
var myMatrix = [
  [0, 1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6, 7],
  [8, 9, 10, 11],
  [12, 13, 14, 15]
];

function rotateMatrixClockwise(matrix) {
  var array = [];
  var long = matrix.length;
  var result1 = new Array(long).fill(array);
  var result2 = [[], [], [], []];
  console.log("Empty result1:");
  console.log(result1);
  console.log("Empty result2:");
  console.log(result2);
  for (var row = 0; row < long; row++) {
    for (var col = 0; col < long; col++) {
      result1[row][col] = matrix[long - col - 1][row];
      result2[row][col] = matrix[long - col - 1][row];
    }
  }
  console.log("Result1:");
  console.log(result1);
  console.log("Result2:");
  console.log(result2);
  console.log('array', array);
}

rotateMatrixClockwise(myMatrix)
```

Comment: So, let me get this straight: it passes the new array by reference four times to the Array.fill()? That's bad. I've just tried changing `[]` to `new Array` and it does the same thing. Is there a way that it creates new arrays each time other than a for loop?

Comment: you could map the empty array, but you still need some iteration.

Comment: @Tyrannogina new Array(100).fill(0).map(Array)

Comment: @Jonasw I don't understand how is this supposed to help. It just returns an array of 100 arrays filled with 0, 0 and another array with 100 length filled with zeros.

Comment: @Tyrannogina looks like its better to write Array(100).fill(0).map(_=>[]); ...http://jsbin.com/viqexunero/edit?console

Comment: Could you explain to me that sintax? I've never seen it before

Comment: @Tyrannogina Array(100) creates a new array with length 100, fill(0) fills it with 0s, and map replaces the zeros with new [] ...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain very well. I meant the `_=>[]` part. I've seen that => is like abbreviating a function, but _?

Comment: the underscore denotes in functions a not used variable, which is a bit shorter to write than `() => `.